# Deadlock in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

So I'm not sure where the issue is occurring, I feel like this is a basic locking setup. Each thread tries to grab the lock and the one that does can go through the critical section while the other has to wait until the thread releases the lock.

But the odd thing is that my 'numLanesLeft' is sometimes equal for for threads.

For example, it should be:

```
Thread 1 - 16   -  Thread 2 - 16
Thread 1 - 15   -  Thread 2 - 14
Thread 1 - 12   -  Thread 2 - 13
```

or something similar all the way down to 0 but I tend to get:

```
Thread 1 - 16   -  Thread 2 - 16
Thread 1 - 14   -  Thread 2 - 14
Thread 1 - 12   -  Thread 2 - 13
```

where both threads have the same numLanesLeft

-

```
void ShooterAction(int rate,Color PlayerColor, int numRound) {

        numLanesLeft = Gallery->Count();

        // used to get the random lane
        int randLane;

        int getColor;

        // while there are still lanes that haven't been shot at
        while(numLanesLeft > 0) {

           // only one operation, share lock
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock);
           printf("color: %i numLanesLeft: %i \n", PlayerColor, numLanesLeft);

           // randomly pick a lane between 0 - 15
           randLane = rand() % 16;

           // if Rouge picked a lane that has already been fired at, look for a free lane
           while(Gallery->Get(randLane) != white) {
              randLane = rand() % 16;
           }

           // set the lane's colour
           getColor = Gallery->Set(randLane, PlayerColor);

           // set the thread to wait X amount of time to simulate a shot        
           usleep(1000000/rate);

           // decrement the number of lanes
           numLanesLeft--;

           // upon lock for other threads
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock);
        }
}
```

Results for printf("color: %i numLanesLeft: %i \n", PlayerColor, numLanesLeft)

```
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 16 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 15 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 14 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 12 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 12 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 11 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 10 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 9 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 9 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 8 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 7 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 6 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 5 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 4 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 3 
color: 2 numLanesLeft: 2 
color: 1 numLanesLeft: 1
```

Comment: where can we see the result of printf("color: %i numLanesLeft: %i \n", PlayerColor, numLanesLeft); ?

Comment: Just added the results. For most of the time it works but there will be occurrences of what I believe is a deadlock when two threads contain the same numLanesLeft

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the first line in the method

```
numLanesLeft = Gallery->Count();
```

numLanesLeft  is a global variable than being accessed and updated by more than one thread without any lock.

if first thread start and did 16, 15, 14 and only after than second thread starting running he will reset the value of numLanesLeft at the beginning of the method.

second issue: the condition (numLanesLeft > 0) might change between the time the thread checked it and starting waiting for the lock and the lock being released, so inside the critical second it more safe to check if the condition (numLanesLeft > 0) is still valid before starting to run it.

other than that i can't find any reason why you are having such results !!

Note: its recommended to use "cout" instead of "printf" in c++

Comment: But shouldn't the `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock);` prevent any threads from entering until it numLanesLeft has been changed? Once one thread gains access, the other will have to wait and the thread that got the lock will change the value of numLanesLeft, shouldn't the thread waiting update it's numLanesLeft before entering the critical section?

Comment: first Gallery->Count() call is done outside of the critical section, try making another call to Gallery->Count() inside the critical section to make sure the values is correct

Comment: But the Gallery->Count is a set number, it will always be 16

Comment: Also could you elaborate a bit of the second part you mentioned about the while loop. I do believe there is an issue there but I can't seem to find it. Sorry I am not too familiar with how locking works.